# If clause with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I seem to be lost or just seem to be confused. 
To simplify the problem: I want to check whether each in an array holds true and if and only if all are true it should return a specific value.

```
var trueArray=[true,true,true,true];
```

As in my code, the array can have length up to 100 elements, I can't simply check for every element but need a for loop.

```
for(var i=0;i<trueArray.length;i++){
   if(trueArray[i]===true)
  {
     //do something
  }
}
```

However, the above code does something on each step of the loop but I only want it to do something once every condition held true and not in between. Can't think of the solution at the moment?

Comment: You can't avoid checking every element. That's the nature of arrays.

Comment: Also what exactly do you mean by "not inbetween"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
if (trueArray.every(function(x) { return x; })) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: I was going to post that, but was fiddling around, and figured it could be done as ............................................. -> `if ( trueArray.every(Number) ) { ...` which is cooler !

Comment: Why not `trueArray.every(Boolean)`?

Comment: No. The argument to `every` has to be a function. It tests whether that function returns `true` for every element.

Answer (score 2):

If it's guaranteed to be a `boolean` you can check if any of them are false instead of if they're all true with [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
if(trueArray.indexOf(false) === -1) {
   // none are false, so do stuff
}
```

You wouldn't need to use a loop or create a function.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a check variable who is already true and set it to false if one of your array values is false. After that, check if it's true and do something.

Example:

```
var trueArray=[true,true,true,true];
var bCheckArrayVal = true;

for(var i=0;i<trueArray.length;i++){
   if(trueArray[i]===false){
     bCheckArrayVal = false;
   }

   if (bCheckArrayVal) {
      // do something if true
   } else {
      // do something if false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
var currentValue = true;
for(var i=0;i<trueArray.length;i++){
     if(trueArray[i]===false){
         currentValue = false;
     }
}
if(currentValue === true){
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should short circuit the logic as soon as you get a false value, must answers are not getting your question because of the misleading logic you put inside the for even though you only want it done once if all values are true.

You need something like

var flag=true;
for(var i =0;i

if (flag) { do something}

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this...

```
var trueArray=[true, true, true, true];
var allTrue=false;
for(var i=0;i<trueArray.length;i++){
   if(trueArray[i]===false){
       allTrue=false;
       break;
   }
   else
   {
       allTrue=true;
   }
}
if(allTrue==true)
{
      // do something if all values are true
}
```

You must break the loop if the false value is detected.